# Invoking batch script with specific user from TFS build server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm new to TFS and need help to overcome following problem.

I have a desktop which has a licensed testing tool and automated tests developed using that tool. The license of the tool is tied up to the user logged in to that desktop.
Now I have created a batch file for my automated tests and I want to call this batch file from TFS. I've installed TFS agent on the desktop where that tool is and on TFS server configured a build definition which runs this batch file, everything working well till here.

The problem is, when the batch script is called by the TFS agent (I think) it is involved as SYSTEM user and not the user which is tied up to the license. Due to this the license check fails and my tests are unable to run.
Is there any way to tell TFS to run the batch script using a specific user ?

Answer (score 0):

The batch scripts are run using the build service account. If you want to run the batch script using a specific account, you need to change your build agent service account.

For TFS 2015 Build agent, run the command:

```
C:\Agent\Agent\VsoAgent.exe /ChangeWindowsServiceAccount
```

Please refer to this document to change the account:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v1-windows

If you use TFS 2017 Build agent, just [re-configure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#choose-interactive-or-service-mode) it and specify that account when you reconfigure it.

Comment: If the agent is used by more than one project it`s no good idea to switch the identity of the agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PowerShell wrapper script to start a executable with different identity.

```
param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$executable,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [string[]]$arguments,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [string]$workingDirectory
)


$secpassword = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$password = $null
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$secPassword)

$workingDirectory = if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($workingDirectory)){(Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName}

Start-Process $executable -ArgumentList $arguments -WorkingDirectory $workingDirectory -Credential ($credentials)
```

Create a hidden variable 'password' in your build or release definition with the password and set the visibility to hidden.

Call this script with the powershell step:

```
-username "username" -password = $(password) -executable "myExecutable" -arguments '-param "param1"','-param2 "param2"','-param3"d:\directory\with blanks in a path\"'
```